# Prolog: Predicate that combines the elements in a list with same value

Tags: prolog

Given the following list:

```
S = [(1,100), (1,125), (2,175), (3,100), (3,250), (3,350), (5,65)]
```

I need to write a function that will create a new list in such a way that the corresponding element in the new list will have the same first value as the value from the element in the first list, but the second value will be the sum of the second values where from the first list where first values are equal.

For the above list the resulting list should be like this:

```
F = [(1,225), (2,175), (3,700), (5,65)]
```

Comment: If this is for SWI-Prolog, consider converting to pairs, then use group_pairs_by_key/3 then use sum_list/2 on values for each key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
go(L) :-
    S = [(1,100), (1,125), (2,175), (3,100), (3,250), (3,350), (5,65)],
    % Start with the first tuple
    S = [(Index, Num)|S0],
    sum_tuples(S0, Index, Num, L).
    

% Finish adding
sum_tuples([], Index, Total, [(Index, Total)]).

sum_tuples([(Index, Num)|Tail], Index, Total, L) :-
    !,
    % Increment the running total
    Total1 is Num + Total,
    sum_tuples(Tail, Index, Total1, L).

% Record the final total for the previous index
sum_tuples([(Index, Num)|Tail], PrevIndex, Total, [(PrevIndex, Total)|L]) :-
    % Start with the new Index
    sum_tuples(Tail, Index, Num, L).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- time(go(L)).
% 14 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (89% CPU, 261721 Lips)
L = [(1,225),(2,175),(3,700),(5,65)].
```

Answer (score 0):

Guy Coder's comment says "*If this is for SWI-Prolog, consider converting to pairs, then use group_pairs_by_key/3 then use sum_list/2 on values for each key.*". Assuming we call `(A,B)` a tuple and `A-B` a pair, that could look like:

```
tuple_pair((A,B), A-B).

solve(Tuples, Result):-
    maplist(tuple_pair, Tuples, Pairs),
    sort(1, @=<, Pairs, SortedPairs),
    group_pairs_by_key(SortedPairs, KeysGroups),
    findall((K, GSum), (member(K-G, KeysGroups), sum_list(G, GSum)), Result).
```

then

```
?- solve([(1,100), (1,125), (2,175), (3,100), (3,250), (3,350), (5,65)], Answer).

Answer = [(1,225), (2,175), (3,700), (5,65)]
```

Comment: could be more idiomatic ? `solve(Tuples, Result):-
    maplist([(A, B), A-B]>>true, Tuples, Pairs),
    keysort(Pairs, Sorted),
    group_pairs_by_key(Sorted, KeysGroups),
    maplist([K-G, K-S]>>sum_list(G, S), KeysGroups, Result).
`